# Uniformly convergence of the $f_n (x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {x^2 \over kx^2 + n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$Q)$ Determine uniformly convergence of the $f_n(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$

$$f_n (x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {x^2 \over kx^2 + n}$$

---

I found the limit of the functions $f(x)=lim_{n \to \infty } f_n(x) = ln(x^2 +1)$

Hence all I left to show the either "$\Vert f_n(x) - f(x) \Vert \not \to 0$" or "$\Vert f_n(x) - f(x) \Vert \to 0$" as $n \to \infty$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

But I can't find the proper method to show above. What should I do next?

Still I don't know that $f_n$ is(or isn't) uniformly converge to $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$

P.s.) Surely another method for "showing the uniformly convergence or not" always welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln (1+n^{2})-f_n(n)=\ln (1+n^{2})-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac {n^{2}}{kn^{2}+n}>\ln (1+n^{2})- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 k > 2\ln n- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 k\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Dear, Mr. @Kavi Ramam Murthy, Would you tell me the reason why the $2 ln n - {1 \over 2} \sum{1 \over k}$ goes $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ for me? Because In my thought that term would be $\infty - \infty$, Hence I can't ensure that value is $\pm\infty$ or $r \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @se-hyuckyang $\int_1^{n} \frac 1 x dx= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} \frac 1 x dx>\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} \frac 1 {k+1} dx$. From this show that $2\ln n-\sum \frac 1 k >2\ln n -1-\ln n$.

Comment: How does one find that $lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = ln(x^2+1)$ ? If I may ask?

Comment: @TheMercury79. Divide numerator and denominator by $x^2$. The summation write as harmonic numbers. Now, use their asymptotics.

Comment: Thanks, but I did that before I asked and I still didn't/don't see it. As for using asymptotics, if I understand correctly $k$ vanishes as $n$ becomes large so I end up with $x^2 / n$. The only thing I can relate to the Maclaurin series for $ln(1+x^2)$ is the $n$ in the denominator. But don't know what to do with $x^2$ as the series for $ln(1+x^2)$ has $x^{2n}$ in it And is alternating.

Comment: @ThrMercury79 Compare the sum with an integral as you do in the integral test. You will easily get the pointwise limit from the integral.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate from $n ~to~ \infty$ But I don't know what to integrate. The original sum gives an integral that diverges to $\infty$. And I'm trying to do what Claude suggested and integrate that but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @TheMercury79 Did you compare $f_n(x)$ with $\int_1^{n} \frac {x^{2}} {tx^{2}+n} dt$?

Comment: No. I had problems with knowing what interval to integrate over. I asked this as a question of my own and got a nice answer. Yours is a little different, but also yields $\ln (1+x^2)$ in the limit n goes to infinity. I can see that now, but I'm still struggling to understand what Claude meant by using asymptotics. Thank you.